# Terraform create a Cloudwatch rule with multiple targets

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

From the Terraform docs - https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/cloudwatch_event_target.html

I don't see an option to map multiple targets to the same Cloudwatch rule. It only takes an `arn` field which accepts one resource. I'm trying to map 5 Lambdas to the same Cloudwatch rule. Does Terraform support this?

EDIT: How can I attach only 5 lambdas? If I've created 15 lambdas, I want to attach 5 each to 3 cloudwatch rules.

Comment: here is what I did. I ignore the "target_id" (very important), and use looping for creating multiple aws_cloudwatch_event_target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working! I had to divide the count of the rules by 5 when I assigned targets to rules. This is roughly what it looks like:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "arule" {
  count       = "${ceil(length(var.lambda_arns) / 5.0)}"  // Needs to be 5.0 to force float computation
  name        = "${var.rule_name}${format("-%d", count.index)}"
  is_enabled  = true
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "atarget" {
  depends_on = ["aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.arule"]
  count = "${length(var.lambda_arns)}"
  rule  = "${aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.arule.*.name[count.index / 5]}"
  arn   = "${var.lambda_arns[count.index]}"
}
```

I created the event rules based on the number of lambdas (i.e., if there are 10 lambdas, 2 rules are created).

I created the targets based on number of lambdas (i.e., if there are 10 lambdas, 10 targets are created).

I assigned the targets proportionally among the rules by dividing the `count.index` by 5 (the same logic used to determine the count of rules).

Comment: You based your solution on my answer and I don't even get a thumbs up. Not cool, dude.

Comment: No I didn't take anything from your solution, I was already using `count` and had a 1-to-1 mapping of targets to rules. My question was around mapping 5 targets to one rule. I'm also not sure your solution would work if `count > 5` since AWS doesn't support more than 5 targets to a rule.

Comment: What about creating multiple `aws_cloudwatch_event_rule` which have multiple targets?

Comment: @covfefe can you pls also attach here how does your variable lambda_arn looks like

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you created all your lambas using the same terraform resource with count, you can use count on this as well:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "cw_target" {
    count = length(aws_lambda_function.my_lambdas)
    rule = "${aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.my_rule.name}"
    arn = "${aws_lambda_function.my_lambdas.*.arn[count.index]}"
}
```

Comment: How can I attach only 5 lambdas? If I've created 15 lambdas, I want to attach 5 each to 3 cloudwatch rules.

Comment: Because there's a limit of 5 targets to a cloudwatch rule I believe

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did. I ignore the "target_id" of resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" (very important), and use local variables (define your local vars, this example: "targets"), and looping for the local vars, and creating multiple aws_cloudwatch_event_target, and multiple assessment templates.

```
locals {
  stack_name_prefix = "Inspector"

  rules_package_arn_cis = "arn:aws:inspector:ap-southeast-2:454640832652:rulespackage/0-Vkd2Vxjq"

  default_target = {
    rules : [local.rules_package_arn_cis],
    duration : 3600
  }

  targets = [
    merge(local.default_target, {
      name : "data_indexer",
      tags : {
        Function = "LR - DX"
      },
    }),
    merge(local.default_target, {
      name : "ai_engine",
      tags : {
        Function = "LR - AIE"
      },
    }),
    merge(local.default_target, {
      name : "data_processor",
      tags : {
        Function = "LR - Data Processor"
      },
    }),
    merge(local.default_target, {
      name : "platform_manager",
      tags : {
        Function = "LR - PM"
      },
    })
  ]
}
resource "aws_inspector_assessment_template" "assessment_template" {
  count              = length(local.targets)
  name               = "${local.stack_name_prefix}_${local.targets[count.index]["name"]}_assessment_template"
  target_arn         = aws_inspector_assessment_target.assessment[count.index].arn
  duration           = local.default_target.duration
  rules_package_arns = [local.rules_package_arn_cis]
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "event_target_for_inspector_assessment_template" {
  count = length(local.targets)
  rule  = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.event_rule_for_inspector_assessment_template.name
  //  target_id = "amazon_inspector_assessment" ## Don't USE target_id, it will mess up the cloudwatch event target, and only generated one target instead of 4
  arn      = aws_inspector_assessment_template.assessment_template[count.index].arn
  role_arn = aws_iam_role.inspector_assessment_template.arn
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    module "eventbridgetarget" {
      for_each  = var.rule_and_target_details
      source    = "git::ssh://git@bitbucket.int.ally.com/tf/terraform-modules-aws-eventbridge.git//modules/target?ref=v1"
      rule_arn  = module.eventbridgerule.rule.arn
      name      = each.value.name
      namespace = module.namespace.lower_short_name
      tags      = module.namespace.tags
      #arn = module.lambda.arn
      arn = each.value.arn
    }

Now in the tfvars pass the value like below:
rule_and_target_details = {
  "firsttarget" = {
    name = "getentities"
    arn = "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:2XXXXXXX:92mchkioeh/api/GET/getEntities"
  }
  "secondtarget" = {
    name = "getactivitylog"
    arn = "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:2XXXXXX:92mchkioeh/api/GET/getActivityLog"
  }
  "thirdtarget" = {
    name = "searchactivitylog"
    arn = "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:XXXXXX:92mchkioeh/api/GET/searchActivityLog"
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).